# Dropbox API Only Showing Photos Folder

Tags: dropbox-api

My web app requests full Dropbox Access and uses OAuth to authenticate users.

For 99% of users, when I make a request to get metadata/info about their dropbox files I get returned every folder/file in their Dropbox.

However, we have some users that when I request metadata/info it ONLY returns the dropbox /Photos folder (you know, the one with the sample pictures in it).

Why would the API for some users only return that folder?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that an app with the full Dropbox permission would only see the /Photos folder and not other items in the account. If you are getting replies with only /Photos, it seems likely that those users do only have that folder in their account, and nothing else. One thing that may be misleading here is if you're expecting to see a /Public folder too, but don't. Note that new accounts [don't get a Public folder by default](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16), and even those that did can delete it anyway.

However, if you are seeing /metadata responses from the Dropbox API that are missing items that you are sure exist in the account (e.g., if you have access to the account and see them on the Dropbox web site), [open a Dropbox API ticket](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact) with the details so we can investigate.